# Quick Book Integration with C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, connection-string, quickbooks

I have `Quick book application` installed in my system. And i have created few vendors and customers list.

Quick Book:  `QuickBooks Simple Start 2010 Free Edition`

Database : `QuickBooks Database Server Manager`

DB Version : `11.0.1.2584`

Computer Name : `SYS13`

From my Windows C# application, I'm trying to add the list of vendors and customer by reading the `Excel`. I'm generating the XML and based on Excel inputs.

Every thing is Ok. But the Connectivity is not happening between `My C# app` and `Quick Book Database`.

**I'm getting below Error:**

```
Can't connect to the database.
```

**Connection String** : `Computer Name=SYS13;Company Data=Demo VSS;Version=11.0.1.2584`

**Code i have Tried to Connect:**

```
     try
     {
           rp.OpenConnection("VendorAdd", "VendorAdd");
           MessageBox.Show(connString);
           ticket = rp.BeginSession(connString);

           response = rp.ProcessRequest(ticket, input);
           requestXML = input.ToString();
           responseXML = response.ToString();

     }
     catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
     {
           MessageBox.Show("COM Error Description = " + ex.Message, "COM error");
           return;
     }
     finally
     {
           if (ticket != null)
           {
               rp.EndSession(ticket);
           }
           if (rp != null)
           {
               rp.CloseConnection();
           }
      };
```

Any Ideas why? Any sample source codes regarding this app?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickbooks integration requires that your application is registered with the company quickbooks file (.qbw I believe). In order for the connection to even take place, you have to run this application directly against the quickbooks installation while quickbooks is running, and authorize your application for integration into quickbooks. I'll dig up the relative links in a follow-up edit.

*EDIT* here are the links that pointed me in the right direction:
http://www.qodbc.com/qodbcconnect.htm
http://www.ehow.com/how_8478505_add-integrated-application-quickbooks.html
http://www.vtechnologies.com/kb.htm?prodid=2&kbid=797F8F94-3706-480D-A357-31B80AE2D011&

There are some other things that could be going on as well. Inspect any COM exceptions that you are getting back and investigate their codes directly. They will at least point you in a good direction. The one I tend to get most often is the COM exception that is telling me that I don't have QuickBooks open and running while I'm trying to access it.

If you get this in an exception, then you need to open quickbooks before you try and connect to it:

```
HRESULT: 0x80040430
```

In general, though, you code should look something like the following:

```
public IVendorRetList GetVendors(string filePath, string appName)
{
var _sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
_sessionManager.CommunicateOutOfProcess(true);
_sessionManager.OpenConnection2(string.Empty, appName, ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
_sessionManager.BeginSession(filePath, ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
_request = _sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 12, 0);
_request.AppendVendorQueryRq();
//do somethign to filter your vendor query here.
var response = _sessionManager.DoRequests(_request);
var vendorList = (IVendorRetList)response.ResponseList.GetAt(0).Detail;
return vendorList;
}
```

Comment: I have given this permissions already and tried. Its Not connecting. Is my connection string correct?

Comment: when i open `QuickBooks Database Server Manager` under Database server tab its displaying `No Files are Connected` even though if i open QB App.

Comment: See my most recent edits. I had little to no success using OpenConnection. All the links I reviewed on Intuit's dev site pointed me to use OpenConnection2 as I have done in the answer I edited above.

Comment: what is the reference for this "QBSessionManager" -- I mean namespace and DLL

Comment: QBSessionManager comes from using QBFC12Lib : which is the DLL that comes in the QuickBooks SDK.

Comment: In my `D:\Program Files\Intuit\QuickBooks 2010` there is no DLL named `QBFC12Lib` from where i can refer this???

Comment: Can u please come to chat room here:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28436/c-developers

Comment: quickbooks SDK installer link: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads